# Combinatorics- to place rooks!

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Find the number of ways to place 3 rooks on a 5 × 5 chess board so
that no two of them attack each other
The way I tried this question was that there are $5C_3$ ways to choose a row and a column in which 3 rooks can be placed so I got $5C_3^2$ but it is wrong.
The second way I thought was that 1st rook can be placed in any of the first 5 blocks of a row and 2nd rook in 4 ways so total comes out to be $5!$ ways but thats wrong please point out my mistakes

Comment: How did you get 5! ? You're only placing 3 rooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial work of $~\left[\binom{5}{3}\right]^2 = 100$ 
is the **right starting point**.

In effect, you have determined that there are 100 possible ways of choosing the pertinent (3 rows) and (3 columns).

Now, you have to consider how many ways are there of placing 3 rooks in a 3 $\times$ 3 chessboard, so that they don't attack each other.

Let $R_i$ denote the rook placed in row $i$.

Then, there are three choices (i.e. columns) that $R_1$ can be placed in, and then two (remaining) columns for $R_2.$

Final answer:

$$\left[\binom{5}{3}\right]^2 \times 3! = 600.$$